# DB model Merise for Users Segment / audiance

Tags: node.js

I am working on survey site.
I want to do 2 features and I can't model them

1 - Client choose audiance like facebook ads (Age - sex ...)
2 - Create a segment that will see a specific survey.

I have no idea how to have a good model database and stack for do that

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MYSQL, and i'm looking to ELK possibility